# how to add to a list from another list in jdk 8

Tags: java-8

I have a the code as below

```
public void getList(List l){
    List newList=new ArrayList();
    l.forEach(x -> {
        Object o = new Object[]{x.getId()};
        newList.add(o);
    });
    sendList(newList);
}
```

Basically I am reading from a list then iterating the list and creating an list of Object array and then sending the newList to another method.

The above method is working fine but this code looks ugly for me as I am creating a new list then iterating it using foreach loop and then assigning it to new object array.

Can some suggest a better way?

Comment: Don't use raw types.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis I have just provided an example. In my real code, I  do use generics and thanks for editing my post

Comment: If you want to get help for the real code, you have to provide a real code. Otherwise all the hints and answers you get would narrow the generics instead what you are really asking for.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis thanks for your suggestions, will surely post real codes in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You had two syntactical errors in the code (I have fixed them to avoid closing question for typos).
- Don't use raw types.
- There is no `Object#getId` method. For that reason, I assume a list passed to the method  has a generic type of an object that has this method. Let's say:

  ```
  interface MyObject {
     Object getId();
  }
  ```

Now, the intention and the code seems clear. You have basically two ways to achieve it.

1. **For-each**: This is equal to your attempt, however, you have to use generics:

   ```
   public void getList(List<MyObject> l) {
       List<Object> newList=new ArrayList<>();
       l.forEach(x -> {
           Object o = new Object[] {x.getId()};
           newList.add(o);
      });
      sendList(newList);
   }
   ```
2. **Stream API**: You can achieve effectively the same result using methods `map` and `collect` collecting to a list.

   ```
   public void getList(List<MyObject> l) {
       List<Object> newList = l.stream()
                               .map(x -> new Object[] {x.getId()})
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
       sendList(newList);
   }
   ```

**Note**: Are you sure you want to call `sendList` in a getter whatever it does?

Comment: if in case I need to create 2 Object lists then what would your map method looks like. I tried .map(x->{}Object o=new Object[]{x.getId()};Object o2=new Object[]{x.getName()} then I am getting compile time error

Comment: The type `x` must have these methods. The list you are getting the objects from must be generic of that type.